# String Replacing in Regex

Tags: regex, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to replace text in string using regex. I accomplished it in c# using the same pattern but in swift its not working as per needed.

Here is my code:

```
var pattern = "\\d(\\()*[x]"

let oldString = "2x + 3 + x2 +2(x)"

let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(pattern, withString:"*" as String, options:NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)


print(newString)
```

What I want after replacement is :

> "2*x + 3 +x2 + 2*(x)"

What I am getting is :

> "* + 3 + x2 +*)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

(?<=\d)(?=x)|(?<=\d)(?=\()

This pattern matches not any characters in the given string, but zero width positions in between characters.

For example, (?<=\d)(?=x) This matches a position in between a digit and 'x'

(?<= is look behind assertion (?= is look ahead.

(?<=\d)(?=\()    This matches the position between a digit and '('

So the pattern before escaping:

(?<=\d)(?=x)|(?<=\d)(?=\()

Pattern, after escaping the parentheses and '\'

\(?<=\\d\)\(?=x\)|\(?<=\\d\)\(?=\\\(\)
```